# Issues in returning a List<int> from a method and printing values in C#

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-core-3.0

I have a method like this `static List<int> Compare(List<int> a, List<int> b)`
I would like this function to `return [aPoints bPoints]` something like `[2 1]` 
But, I'm stuck on storing the values after the loop with `if` statements and putting them in score.
I tried this:

```
static List<int> Compare(List<int> a, List<int> b)
{        
    int aPoints = 0;
    int bPoints = 0;
    List<int> score = new List<int>() { aPoints, bPoints }; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > b[i])
        {
            aPoints++;
        }
        else if (a[i] < b[i])
        {
            bPoints++;
        }
    }

    return score;
}
```

And print them on:

```
static void Main(string[] args){}
```

Comment: ints are not passed by reference. they are passed by value. When you create `score` you are feeding it `0` and `0`. These values do not get updated when `aPoints` and `bPoints` change. It gets what they are at time of assignment. There is no further link

Comment: @DetectivePikachu Thanks! The List<int> would be passed by Value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a very simple solution. Just create an empty list, and add `aPoints` and `bPoints` to it right before returning to the caller.

```
static List<int> Compare(List<int> a, List<int> b)
{        
    int aPoints = 0;
    int bPoints = 0;
    List<int> score = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > b[i])
        {
            aPoints++;
        }
        else if (a[i] < b[i])
        {
            bPoints++;
        }
    }
    score.Add(aPoints);
    score.Add(bPoints);
    return score;
```

- Or you can just create your list right at the `return` like this:

```
static List<int> Compare(List<int> a, List<int> b)
{        
    int aPoints = 0;
    int bPoints = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > b[i])
        {
            aPoints++;
        }
        else if (a[i] < b[i])
        {
            bPoints++;
        }
    }

    return new List<int>() { aPoints, bPoints};
```

- Also, you could use a more semantically correct way since your list always has 2 values. Use a [tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples):

```
static (int aPoints, int bPoints) Compare(List<int> a, List<int> b)
{        
    int aPoints = 0;
    int bPoints = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > b[i])
        {
            aPoints++;
        }
        else if (a[i] < b[i])
        {
            bPoints++;
        }
    }

    return (aPoints, bPoints);
}
```

Following up on your comment, if you want to print the contents of what the `Compare` method returns, then, for a `List<int>` you can do:

```
List<int> ret = Compare(someList, anotherList);
foreach (int n in ret)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

- Or you can use a classic `for` loop like this:

```
List<int> ret = Compare(someList, anotherList);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ret[i]);
}
```

However, in this loop, it's assumed that your list will **always** have 2 elements inside. A general approach would be to change the loop definition to `for (int i = 0; i < ret.Count; i++)` so that it iterates over every available item in the list like with the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thanks! on your second example, how would you print those values on the static void Main? Something like: Console.WriteLine(Program.Compare(a, b)); this comes up as System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

Comment: Yes, because you're actually printing the type and not the contents. Edit the question to include your comment, I'll edit the answer to include the printing.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're creating the list *before* you give `aPoints` and `bPoints` useful values. When you add `aPoints` and `bPoints` to the list, you're adding the *values* - so you end up with a list of `[0, 0]`.

Instead, you should create the list at the end - and you don't really need a variable for it:

```cs
static List<int> Compare(List<int> a, List<int> b)
{        
    int aPoints = 0;
    int bPoints = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > b[i])
        {
            aPoints++;
        }
        else if (a[i] < b[i])
        {
            bPoints++;
        }
    }

    return new List<int>() { aPoints, bPoints };
}
```

A few things to note:

- Your code always loops 3 times, regardless of how long `a` and `b` are. While that may be okay now, it's a bit inflexible... any reason you don't want to check they're the same length, and then iterate over them completely?
- You might want to *consider* returning a tuple instead:

```cs
static (int aPoints, int bPoints) Compare(List<int> a, List<int> b)
{        
    int aPoints = 0;
    int bPoints = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > b[i])
        {
            aPoints++;
        }
        else if (a[i] < b[i])
        {
            bPoints++;
        }
    }

    return (aPoints, bPoints);
}
```

After all, the list you'll return *always* has two elements, and I suspect the caller won't want to treat it as a general-purpose list anyway.

---

**Printing the results**

If you're still using the list approach for returning the values, your Main method should look something like this:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    List<int> a = ... ; // However you want to populate this
    List<int> b = ... ; // However you want to populate this
    List<int> results = Compare(a, b);
    Console.WriteLine($"Score for a: {results[0]}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Score for b: {results[1]}");
}
```

If you use the tuple approach, you can be clearer:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    List<int> a = ... ; // However you want to populate this
    List<int> b = ... ; // However you want to populate this
    var results = Compare(a, b);
    Console.WriteLine($"Score for a: {results.aPoints}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Score for b: {results.bPoints}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! On your first example. it loops 3 times because of: 
List<int> a = new List<int>() { 15, 32, 44 };
List<int> b = new List<int>() { 88, 12, 8 };

Comment: @Jacman: But what do you expect to happen if you pass in two smaller lists? Or two bigger lists? Don't you think it might surprise users that it always expects *exactly* 3 elements?

Comment: Makes sense. How would you dynamically go thru the length of this two arrays? Or would you just evaluate each one individually?

Comment: @Jacman: `List<T>.Count` is a property that returns the size of the list. I'd probably start by throwing an exception if the two lists (they're not arrays) aren't the same length, and then use `a.Count` instead of 3 in your loop.

Comment: Yes, a List... I assumed the concept as a collection. But it's a great notation and makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Integers are passed by *value* and not by *reference*. This means when you make a `new List<int>() { aPoints, bPoints };`, the values of `aPoints` and `bPoints`, which are both 0, are copied into the list. Changing their values afterwards won't affect the copies stored in the list.

For this specific situation, the easiest thing would be to simply move your line `List<int> score = new List<int>() { aPoints, bPoints };` after your loop. Then, the points values will be copied over after they've been set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

aPoints and bPoints are value types, not reference types, so put them in the end:

```
static List<int> Compare(List<int> a, List<int> b)
{        
    int aPoints = 0;
    int bPoints = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > b[i])
        {
            aPoints++;
        }
        else if (a[i] < b[i])
        {
            bPoints++;
        }
    }

    return new List<int>() { aPoints, bPoints };
}
```

Comment: Note that even if they were reference types, the *value* of the variable would still end up in the list. If you modified the content of the object that the variable referred to, that would be one thing - but changes in the variables themselves (to refer to different objects) wouldn't be reflected in the list.